# Using cilk++ work stealing

Tags: work-stealing, cilk-plus

I am new to cilk++ and I want to use cilk's work stealing scheduler. I couldn't find much information on this. Can anybody help me regarding this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a specific coding problem? If so, can you please supply your code along with an explanation of where you're having trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of information at the http://cilkplus.org website.

You'll need one of:

- Intel Compose XE
- The GCC "cilkplus" branch
- The Cilk Plus/LLVM development branch

Pointers to all of these are available at http://cilkplus.org/which-license .

There's also a tutorial available at the website - look at http://cilkplus.org/cilk-plus-tutorial .

- Barry